# suggest a way to fix gas and electric charge calculation

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define BASELINE 75.6
#define CONST1 0.11430
#define CONST2 0.12989
#define CONST3 0.22944
#define CONST4 0.32146
#define GAS_BASELINE 12.6
#define CONST5 1.13309
#define CONST6 1.35349

void getInput( long *preElecRead, long *currElecRead, long *preGasRead, long *currGasRead);
double calcOutput( double *kwhConsumed, double *thermsConsumed, double *elecCharges, double *gasCharges, double *totalDue,
            long preElecRead, long currElecRead, long preGasRead, long currGasRead);
void printOutput(long preElecRead, long currElecRead, long preGasRead, long currGasRead,double kwhConsumed, double thermsConsumed,
             double elecCharges, double gasCharges, double totalDue );
double calcKWH(long preElecRead, long currElecRead);
double calcGasTherms(long preGasRead, long currGasRead);
double calcElecCharges(double* kwhConsumed);
double calcGasCharges(double thermsConsumed);
double round100th(double n);
double calcTotalDue(double* gasCharges, double* elecCharges);


int main(void)
{   //Declaration
    long preElecRead;
    long currElecRead;
    long preGasRead;
    long currGasRead;
    double kwhConsumed;
    double thermsConsumed;
    double elecCharges;
    double gasCharges;
    double totalDue;
    //Statement
    getInput(&preElecRead, &currElecRead, &preGasRead, &currGasRead);
    calcOutput(&kwhConsumed, &thermsConsumed, &elecCharges, &gasCharges, &totalDue, preElecRead,
            currElecRead, preGasRead, currGasRead);
    printOutput(preElecRead, currElecRead, preGasRead, currGasRead, kwhConsumed, thermsConsumed, elecCharges, gasCharges,totalDue);

    return 0;
}   //end main

void getInput( long *preElecRead, long *currElecRead, long *preGasRead, long *currGasRead)
{
    printf("Enter previous & current electric meter readings: ", preElecRead, currElecRead);
    scanf("%ld %ld", preElecRead, currElecRead);
    printf("Enter previous & current gas meter readings: ", preGasRead, currGasRead);
    scanf("%ld %ld", preGasRead, currGasRead);
}

double calcOutput( double *kwhConsumed, double *thermsConsumed, double *elecCharges, double *gasCharges, double *totalDue,
            long preElecRead, long currElecRead, long preGasRead, long currGasRead)
{
    *kwhConsumed = calcKWH(preElecRead, currElecRead);
    *thermsConsumed = calcGasTherms(preGasRead, currGasRead);
    *elecCharges = calcElecCharges(kwhConsumed);
    *gasCharges = calcGasCharges(*thermsConsumed);
    *totalDue =  calcTotalDue(gasCharges, elecCharges);
}

double calcKWH(long preElecRead, long currElecRead)
{
    double kwh;

    kwh = (double)currElecRead - (double)preElecRead;

    return kwh;
}

double calcGasTherms(long preGasRead, long currGasRead)
{
    double gas;

    gas = (double)currGasRead - (double)preGasRead;

    return gas;
}

double calcElecCharges(double* kwhConSumed)
{
    double elecCharge ;
    if (*kwhConSumed > 0 && *kwhConSumed <= BASELINE)
    {
        elecCharge = *kwhConSumed * CONST1;
    }
        else
            if ( *kwhConSumed > BASELINE && *kwhConSumed <= (1.3*BASELINE))
                {
                    elecCharge = *kwhConSumed * CONST2;
                }
                else
                   if ( *kwhConSumed > (1.3*BASELINE) && *kwhConSumed <= (2.0*BASELINE))
                    {
                        elecCharge = *kwhConSumed *  CONST3;
                    }
                        else
                            if (*kwhConSumed > 2.0*BASELINE)
                            {
                                elecCharge = *kwhConSumed * CONST4;
                            }
   return  round100th(elecCharge);
}
double calcGasCharges(double thermsConsumed)
{
    double gas;
    // check if therms < 0 and <= baseline
    if (thermsConsumed > 0 && thermsConsumed <= GAS_BASELINE) gas = thermsConsumed * CONST5;
        else
            if (thermsConsumed > GAS_BASELINE) gas = thermsConsumed * CONST6;
    return round100th(gas);

}

double round100th(double n)
{
    if(n > 0 )
    {
        n = (n + 50) / 100 * 100;
    }
    else
    {
        return n = 0;
    }
    return n;
}

double calcTotalDue(double* gasCharges, double* elecCharges)
{
    double i;

    i = (double)(*gasCharges)+ (double)(*elecCharges);// calc total

    return i;
}

void printOutput(long preElecRead, long currElecRead, long preGasRead, long currGasRead,double kwhConsumed, double thermsConsumed,
             double elecCharges, double gasCharges, double totalDue )
{
    printf("Electric:\n");
    printf("Previous: %ld, Current: %ld,     KWH Used: %0.0lf, Charges: %.2lf\n", preElecRead, currElecRead, kwhConsumed, elecCharges);

    printf("Gas:\n");
    printf("Previous: %ld, Current: %ld,  Therms Used: %0.0lf, Charges: %.2lf\n", preGasRead, currGasRead, thermsConsumed, gasCharges);

   printf("Total Charges: %60.2lf", totalDue);
}
```

hi I have a problem with this code i finish the code but somehow my out put for electric charge and and gas charge is different from the test run output used by my professor, I'm thinking that I might not have been using the right formula to calculate gas charge and electric charge. Can anyone show me the right formula to calculate gas charge and electric charge

this is my output

```
Enter previous & current electric meter readings: 80000
80500
Enter previous & current gas meter readings: 990
1030
Electric:
Previous: 80000, Current: 80500,     KWH Used: 500, Charges: 210.73
Gas:
Previous: 990, Current: 1030,  Therms Used: 40, Charges: 104.14
Total Charges:                                                       314.87
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 21.512 s
Press any key to continue.
```

this is the test run output:

```
Enter previous & current electric meter readings: 80000
80500
Enter previous & current gas meter readings: 990
1030
Electric:
Previous: 80000, Current: 80500,     KWH Used: 500, Charges: 135.78
Gas:
Previous: 990, Current: 1030,  Therms Used: 40, Charges: 135.78
Total Charges:                                                       271.56
```

As you can see  the outputs for gas charge and electric charge are different in both using the same input. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can not expect someone to know what formula you want to use :) but I think your problem is in the code and not the formula. Try this:

```
double calcElecCharges(double* kwhConSumed)
{
    double elecCharge ;
    if (*kwhConSumed > 0 && *kwhConSumed <= BASELINE)
    {
        elecCharge = *kwhConSumed * CONST1;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( *kwhConSumed > BASELINE && *kwhConSumed <= (1.3*BASELINE))
            {
                elecCharge = *kwhConSumed * CONST2;
            }
            else
            {
                if ( *kwhConSumed > (1.3*BASELINE) && *kwhConSumed <= (2.0*BASELINE))
                {
                    elecCharge = *kwhConSumed *  CONST3;
                }
                else if (*kwhConSumed > 2.0*BASELINE)
                {
                    elecCharge = *kwhConSumed * CONST4;
                }
                else 
                {
                  //*kwhConSumed < (1.3*BASELINE) || *kwhConSumed > (2.0*BASELINE)
                  //What now??
                }
            }
    }
   return  round100th(elecCharge);
}
double calcGasCharges(double thermsConsumed)
{
    double gas;
    // check if therms < 0 and <= baseline
    if (thermsConsumed > 0 && thermsConsumed <= GAS_BASELINE) 
        gas = thermsConsumed * CONST5;
    else if (thermsConsumed > GAS_BASELINE) 
        gas = thermsConsumed * CONST6;
    else
    {
      //thermsConsumed < 0
      //What now??
    }

    return round100th(gas);

}
```

Or provide the formula you got from professor so someone can check your code.

Answer (score 0):

Some higher-level remarks first.

```
double calcOutput(...);
```

doesn't return anything, and since it receives pointers to all variables it should affect, there is no need for it to return anything. It should be declared

```
void calcOutput(...);
```

Next,

```
double calcElecCharges(double* kwhConsumed);
```

doesn't change the number of consumed KWh, so there's no point in passing a pointer to it. Its kin `calcGasCharges()` takes a plain `double` as argument, and so should `calcElecCharges()`.

In `getInput()`, you pass extraneous arguments to the `printf()` calls:

```
printf("Enter previous & current electric meter readings: ", preElecRead, currElecRead)
printf("Enter previous & current gas meter readings: ", preGasRead, currGasRead);
```

That does no actual harm, since `printf()` just ignores arguments beyond the ones required by the format string, but it's bad style.

Now an implementation error,

```
double round100th(double n)
{
    if(n > 0 )
    {
        n = (n + 50) / 100 * 100;
    }
    else
    {
        return n = 0;
    }
    return n;
}
```

doesn't nearly do what it says on the lid, it basically adds 50 to a positive value and returns 0 for a negative one. The latter may be intended, but for the former, I believe you want to round the value to two places after the decimal point, which - ignoring the finer points of floating-point representation - would be achieved by multiplying by 100, rounding to the nearest integer and dividing by 100,

```
if (n > 0) {
    n = round(100.0*n)/100.0;
}
```

That doesn't nearly produce the desired output still, but without knowing what the actual formulae for the calculation of the charges should be, we cannot diagnose that.

Comment: Nice explanation but don't you think he should learn that at school :)